# Как установить в Colab последнюю версию python, pip (3.11.2), а также обновить обновить модули?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Как установить в Colab последнюю версию python, pip (3.11.2), а также обновитьмодули для работы с новой версией python?

Comment: Вот здесь есть разные рецепты, часть из них правда уже не рабочая. Но там многовато шаманства, проще локально уж локально себе нужный питон поставить и поддерживать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68657341/how-can-i-update-google-colabs-python-version

Comment: У меня планшет Samsung Galaxy S8+ Tablet и не уверен, что  на нем полноценная анаконда заработает и производительность будет хорошей